# how to pass deviceName in conf.js through command line before starting webdriver instance

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

Currently I'm trying emulate chrome browser on mobile devices (e.g Apple iPad\Samsung Galaxy). It works fine when hardcoded deviceName are passed in conf.js.

But I want to change devices on fly. I've tried passing deivceName parameter in command line but with no luck. It didn't update value in conf.js but after webdriver instance is started I see updated param values:

```
protractor mobiledevice.js --params.device="Apple iPhone 5"
```

-

```
"use strict";

var config = require('./conf.js').config;

config.params = {
    device: 'Google Nexus 6'
}


config.capabilities = {
    'chromeOptions': {
        'mobileEmulation': {
            'deviceName': config.params.device
        }
    }
};

exports.config = config;
```

Question: how do I emulate device which is passed as parameter through command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the [`getMultiCapabilities` function](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/9144494a28dac5a0409de4c5384e933f2d2f8156/docs/referenceConf.js#L186):

```
exports.config = {
    getMultiCapabilities: function () {
        return [{
            chromeOptions: {
                mobileEmulation: {
                    deviceName: this.params.device
                }
            }
        }];
    },

    // ...
};
```

Then pass the `device` parameter:

```
protractor mobiledevice.js --params.device="Apple iPhone 5"
```